# Oracle11g database long startup in docker container

Tags: oracle11g, docker

I use https://hub.docker.com/r/jaspeen/oracle-11g/ image for restore db from dump file. After commit and run from image I wait 20 minutes when db OPEN:

```
SQL> select status from v$instance;

STATUS
------------
MOUNTED
```

after 20 minutes

```
SQL> select status from v$instance;

STATUS
------------
OPEN
```

entrypoint.sh log:

```
sqlplus: Database mounted.
alertlog: Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id 1430168652
alertlog: Database mounted in Exclusive Mode
alertlog: Lost write protection disabled
alertlog: Completed: ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
alertlog: Fri Jan 29 05:49:06 2016
alertlog: ALTER DATABASE OPEN
listener: 29-JAN-2016 05:49:06 * service_update * orcl * 0
listener: Fri Jan 29 05:49:29 2016
listener: 29-JAN-2016 05:49:29 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus64)(HOST=ubuntu)(USER=user))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.196.5.92)(PORT=43917)) * establish * orcl * 0
Database mounted in Exclusive Modelistener: Fri Jan 29 05:56:42 2016
listener: 29-JAN-2016 05:56:42 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus64)(HOST=ubuntu)(USER=user))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.196.5.92)(PORT=43925)) * establish * orcl * 0
alertlog: Fri Jan 29 06:04:18 2016
alertlog: Errors in file /opt/oracle/app/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/trace/orcl_m000_86.trc:
alertlog: ORA-01155: the database is being opened, closed, mounted or dismounted
listener: Fri Jan 29 06:06:33 2016
listener: 29-JAN-2016 06:06:33 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus64)(HOST=ubuntu)(USER=user))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.196.5.92)(PORT=43935)) * establish * orcl * 0
listener: Fri Jan 29 06:09:09 2016
listener: 29-JAN-2016 06:09:08 * service_update * orcl * 0
alertlog: Fri Jan 29 06:11:14 2016
alertlog: Thread 1 opened at log sequence 41
alertlog: Current log# 2 seq# 41 mem# 0: /opt/oracle/app/oradata/orcl/redo02.log
alertlog: Successful open of redo thread 1
alertlog: Fri Jan 29 06:11:14 2016
```

Why is so long starded?

```
db_recovery_file_dest_size of 3882 MB is 0.00% used. This is a
alertlog: user-specified limit on the amount of space that will be used by this
alertlog: database for recovery-related files, and does not reflect the amount of
alertlog: space available in the underlying filesystem or ASM diskgroup.
```

May be every time start recovery db?
How to avoid it?

Comment: Just to clarify: the initial startup of the DB - before importing any data - from image takes 20 minutes? That seems excessively long. Personally, I've used https://hub.docker.com/r/alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g/, and the DB is up in less than a minute (however, there's no impdp involved).

Comment: Frank, initial startup of the DB is about 20 seconds. Startup DB with dump 20 minutes. During startup iostat show that 100Mb/s write on the disk. Now I see that docker/aufs/diff take a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

We decide to use zfs on iscsi for db snapshot from prod server. Startup db in 1 minutes.